# How to get http responseCode in Glide listener?

Tags: android, http, listener, android-glide, http-response-codes

I am using Glide to show previews of images located on the remote server. There is a need to handle different response codes in a different way. For example when the server responses with code `202`, I have to wait for certain socket event. Here is my code:

```
fun ImageView.loadRounded(glideUrl: GlideUrl, radius: Int = 20) {
    GlideApp.with(this.context)
            .load(glideUrl)
            .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
            .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(RoundedCorners(radius)))
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    e?.rootCauses?.forEach {
                        logd("${it.message}")
                    }
                    return false
                }
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    return false
                }
            })
            .into(this)
}
```

In the case when server sends response code `202`, in `onLoadFailed` I get this output:

> java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)

It happens because `202` is one of successfull status codes. Glide tries to download picture, but it is not there.

Method `e?.logRootCauses()` doesn't give response codes neither.

**Is there a way to get http response code in Glide listener?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to intercept status code and replace it with another one. For this I have replaced `DataFetcher` implemetation used in `Glide` with modified version.
Here are the steps:

Create `@GlideModule` if you don't have it already:

```
@GlideModule
public class MyGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
        registry.append(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class,
            new MyOkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(new OkHttpClient()));
    }
}
```

where standard `OkHttpUrlLoader` is also replaced with modified version. Unfortunately, you can't just extend standard implementation since you have to interact with private members of it. So It should be a full copy of original `OkHttpUrlLoader`, but return custom `DataFetcher` in `buildLoadData` method. Also `build` method should return instance of modified version of loader:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.bumptech.glide.load.Options;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.GlideUrl;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoader;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoaderFactory;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoaderFactory;

import java.io.InputStream;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

/**
 * A simple model loader for fetching media over http/https using OkHttp.
 */
public class MyOkHttpUrlLoader implements ModelLoader<GlideUrl, InputStream> {

    private final Call.Factory client;

    // Public API.
    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    public MyOkHttpUrlLoader(@NonNull Call.Factory client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handles(@NonNull GlideUrl url) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public LoadData<InputStream> buildLoadData(@NonNull GlideUrl model, int width, int height,
                                               @NonNull Options options) {
        return new LoadData<>(model, new MyOkHttpStreamFetcher(client, model));
    }

    /**
     * The default factory for {@link com.bumptech.glide.integration.okhttp3.OkHttpUrlLoader}s.
     */
    // Public API.
    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    public static class Factory implements ModelLoaderFactory<GlideUrl, InputStream> {
        private static volatile Call.Factory internalClient;
        private final Call.Factory client;

        /**
         * Constructor for a new Factory that runs requests using a static singleton client.
         */
        public Factory() {
            this(getInternalClient());
        }

        /**
         * Constructor for a new Factory that runs requests using given client.
         *
         * @param client this is typically an instance of {@code OkHttpClient}.
         */
        public Factory(@NonNull Call.Factory client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        private static Call.Factory getInternalClient() {
            if (internalClient == null) {
                synchronized (Factory.class) {
                    if (internalClient == null) {
                        internalClient = new OkHttpClient();
                    }
                }
            }
            return internalClient;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ModelLoader<GlideUrl, InputStream> build(MultiModelLoaderFactory multiFactory) {
            return new MyOkHttpUrlLoader(client);
        }

        @Override
        public void teardown() {
            // Do nothing, this instance doesn't own the client.
        }
    }
 }
```

And here is my modified version of DataFetcher, which is almost a copy of a standard implementation (OkHttpStreamFetcher). Difference is that in `onResponse` method I check code, and in case it is `202` I replace it with error code 418:

```
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.bumptech.glide.Priority;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.data.DataFetcher;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.GlideUrl;
import com.bumptech.glide.util.ContentLengthInputStream;
import com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions;
import com.zultys.mobiledroid.utils.logger.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;

/**
 * Fetches an {@link InputStream} using the okhttp library.
 */
public class MyOkHttpStreamFetcher implements DataFetcher<InputStream>, okhttp3.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "OkHttpFetcher";
    private final Call.Factory client;
    private final GlideUrl url;
    private InputStream stream;
    private ResponseBody responseBody;
    private DataCallback<? super InputStream> callback;
    // call may be accessed on the main thread while the object is in use on other threads. All other
    // accesses to variables may occur on different threads, but only one at a time.
    private volatile Call call;

    // Public API.
    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    public ZultysOkHttpStreamFetcher(Call.Factory client, GlideUrl url) {
        this.client = client;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadData(@NonNull Priority priority,
                         @NonNull final DataCallback<? super InputStream> callback) {
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder().url(url.toStringUrl());
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> headerEntry : url.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
            String key = headerEntry.getKey();
            requestBuilder.addHeader(key, headerEntry.getValue());
        }
        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        this.callback = callback;

        call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "OkHttp failed to obtain result", e);
        }
        callback.onLoadFailed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) {
        responseBody = response.body();
        // Code 202 means that file was sent from another MX in MX net,
        // and you have to wait until it gets copied to your MX. After that you will receive
        // csta packet with messageStatus IMS_FILE_DOWNLOAD, and can repeat same request.
        if (response.code() == 202) {
            callback.onLoadFailed(new HttpException("I'm a teapot", 418));
        } else if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            long contentLength = Preconditions.checkNotNull(responseBody).contentLength();
            stream = ContentLengthInputStream.obtain(responseBody.byteStream(), contentLength);
            callback.onDataReady(stream);
        } else {
            callback.onLoadFailed(new HttpException(response.message(), response.code()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup() {
        try {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignored
        }
        if (responseBody != null) {
            responseBody.close();
        }
        callback = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        Call local = call;
        if (local != null) {
            local.cancel();
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Class<InputStream> getDataClass() {
        return InputStream.class;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSource.REMOTE;
    }
 }
```

Comment: is there a way to actually get a hold of the response headers from within the glide.load call?